# asp.net mvc view model validation for version number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to validate my input which can only allow to the version number such as

```
4.0
4.1
4.2
4.2.1
4.2.2
```

This is my field name

```
 public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
```

How can I add validation for my field name on my view model ??
I can only find [Phone] annotation , I can't find anything which can validate for Version Number like this.
Using `RegularExpression` or other way ?

Comment: Try these patterns for `RegularExpressionAttribute`: `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` or `^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$`, or create a custom validation attribute containing one of those patterns.

Comment: Alternative to RegEx - you could use the `SemanticVersioning` Nuget package. This would allow you to specify and validate ranges of versions too. https://github.com/adamreeve/semver.net